# Gallery thumbnails locked

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, gallery, thumbnails

I have a problem with my gallery thumbnails for a few days now. Thumbnails are generated in the *.thumbnails* folder but they are not displayed in the gallery, there is instead a picture with a lock.

How can I solve this? I have already tried to clear data but it didn't work. It seems like there is a broken permission in the gallery application.

[image: screencap]

Comment: Could it be you (or someone else) installed some app locker or gallery locker to the device? Maybe someone's having fun with you. Go to *Google Play* (Web), and browse through the list of apps installed to the device (such a locker might hide on the device itself, hence looking at the web interface; of course, you can also check *Settings->Apps*). That would at least be the most plausible explanation.

Answer (score -1):

I have exactly this problem. There is no gallery locker on the phone. I have removed the thumbnails from the DCIM directory, and Android has re-scanned the SD card and created three sets of thumbnails: Camera, Whatsapp and Wahtsappvid. But when I view them in Gallery, I get the same symptoms as above, with each thumbnail showing as above. If I click on one of these 'blank' thumbnails, the picture displays ok. If I use MediaSee it seems to display all the pictures as thumbnails.
Perhaps of interest may be that the picture above looks like a Motorola Defy Mini phone, which is what I have got. Sorry if this is the wrong way to ask this question, but this is the only post I have seen which shows the problem I have got.

Comment: While this really isn't an answer to the original question, it at least details some things that were tried and didn't work, so it's at least a helpful partial answer. (You'd probably do well to read our [help] though.)